# Inner join 2 tables based on 2 columns in one and one column in the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

[image]

I have two tables I am wanting to inner join. The column of one is `Ordind000.PROCPLANID`. This has the job, the `J000012345`, and suffix, the `.00001` both in this one column. But in the `Job` table that I need to join it to, both the job and the suffix are separate columns.

My guess is I need to use the replace command and write it to a temp table, but I am hoping for a much easier solution. I will also need to strip the decimal at the beginning of the `job` and `suffix` numbers in the `PROCPLANID` columns I think.

Comment: Is the suffix always a single digit?

Comment: You can combine columns in the `ON` clause, for example `table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.PROCPLANID = '.' + table2.job + '     .0000' + table2.suffix` ... that's one way to do it

Comment: Which version of SQL server is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could manipulate this, here is one:

```
SELECT columns
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on 
SUBSTRING(t1.procplanid,2,10) + RIGHT(t1.procplanid,1) = t2.job + t2.suffix
```

This will compare the `job` portion of `procplanid` (without the decimal) `+` the last digit of `procplanid` as the `suffix`, to `job + suffix`

Highlighted examples in the image will become:

- J0000784749: Job = J000078474, Suffix = 9
- J0000760622: Job = J000076062, Suffix = 2